# PostgreSQL without password prompt : .pgpass ignored

Tags: linux, postgresql, scripting, admin

I'm trying to enable root (Ubuntu 8.04) to use psql command without password prompt (for scripting purpose). Everything worked fine with PostgreSQL 8.3, but I migrate to PostgreSQL 8.4 and the login without password doesn't work anymore.

I've a correct `.pgpass` file (the same used for 8.3), the right of `/root/.pgpass` are `0600` but calling psql keep asking for a password.

NB : the `PGPASSFILE` variable is empty, so I assume that the `.pgpass` file is supposed to be used.

Any brilliant idea?

Comment: "strace -o <log_file> psql ... " and then look into the log file for ".pgpass".

Comment: Here are the lines containing .pgpass into the log file                                                      stat("/root/.pgpass", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=37, ...}) = 0
open("/root/.pgpass", O_RDONLY)         = 3
stat("/root/.pgpass", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=37, ...}) = 0
open("/root/.pgpass", O_RDONLY)         = 3

Comment: I've also a line showing that pgsql found the password : read(3, "localhost:5432:dbname:usrname:passw"…, 4096) = 37

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to check if this works:

```
*:*:*:postgres:password_for_postgres_user
```

And then try:

```
VERBOSITY=verbose psql --no-password --user postgres
```

This question should probably be migrated to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: You are right it's more a server administration problem. The problem was that the server was installed right after postgres 8.3 and thus the installation make it run on the port 5433 instead of 5432. I fixed it by editing postgres.conf. Thanks !